# Joins with columns being joined have different lengths

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables,

```
 - emp(empId number(1),empName varchar2(50)) and
 - manager(manId number(5),managerName varchar2(100))
```

And I fire a query -

```
select * from emp e,manager m where e.empId = m.manId; 
update emp set empName= (select managerName from manager where manId='2');
```

Will there be any problem in this sql as length of empName and managerName is different?

Comment: No, the length won't influence. If the strings are equal, it won't be a problem!

Comment: why dont you try it? Read about the varchar datatype and its diff with char datatype in db

Comment: Absolutely no. It will work perfect.

Comment: @ejb_guy i know that varchar can contain variable length of values ..but my question is somewhat diff

Comment: it will compare the column values not matter with the datatypes and their length.

Comment: @jain007 Nope. I dont see what difference you are talking about. Have you tried doing test yourself.

Comment: Second query will cause all emps to have the same manager.

Comment: hey..the thing is i edited that question and did not got replies for the same..thus asked as a separate question

Comment: @jain007, you got a reply right here, asking the question again won't help. If the answer doesn't help you, add a comment to say so. Perhaps say what is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First will work (well, not raise an error), second will raise an error if length of managerName > 50.

It would work with  `substr(managerName, 0, 50)`
and

```
WHERE empId = 2
```

at the end.

By the way, you could have tried !